# Regex extracting specific text ignoring part of result

Tags: regex

I have a text.

```
The overall system blur must be smaller than 12 mrad and diameter shall be less than 20 meters.
```

I want to extract:

```
must be 12
```

I'm using:

```
^(.*?(\bmust be\b[\s*?\D]*\d+)[^$]*)$
```

And I get

```
must be smaller than 12
```

Any way to do this directly? Or better to try to do different groups somehow?

Comment: I suppose there is no solution for you question. But it can be done with the help of programing language (or editor like VSCode/Sublime text). What language are you doing on this problem?

Comment: This can be achieved using backreference. I don't know which language/flavor you are using. In R, this would be this: `gsub(".*(\\bmust be\\b)([^0-9]+)([0-9]+).*", "\\1 \\3", x)`. The result is: `must be 12`

Comment: Did my answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern that you tried, `\D` matches any char except a digit, so this `[\s*?\D]*` could be shortened to just `\D`.

This part `[^$]*` matches any char except a dollar sign. If you intend to match the rest of the line, you can use `.*` instead.

---

You can use 2 capturing groups instead.

```
^.*?\b(must be)\b\D*(\d+).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OJogAW/1)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups like for example `$1 $2`